# Is there a glossary about which infrared (IR) colors which body parts reflect?

Tags: infrared-radiation

I am doing medical research and I'm trying to find parts of the body that look about the same to the human eye, but reflect different "colors" in IR, so that using a light source and a camera of that frequency helps to distinguish between them. Thus I was wondering if there is a glossary out there that lists all the colors (visible or invisible to the human eye) for all body parts (cells, bacteria, organs etc.) that get reflected.

I'd also be interested in literature on that topic, but it's sort of difficult to feed the right words into search engines without getting tons of unrelated results.

I originally posted this [here](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/80958/is-there-a-glossary-about-which-infrared-ir-colors-which-body-parts-reflect), but according to the comments it seems to be more like a physics problem.

Comment: I have no direct answer to your question. However, I agree that it is quite probable that you may find an answer in the physics community. If you do not know it already, I would mention this page https://www.nist.gov/programs-projects/reflectance-measurements-human-skin as a promising starting point for information on the subject. And probably a direct contact of NIST's staff on your problem could be one of the fastest way to find what you are looking for.

Comment: Not the answer, because you are asking for an infinite amount of data in a huge table; just a comment: a beautiful image that shows a single data point: at 1600 nm, skin is black and hair is white.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infrared#/media/File:Infrared_portrait_comparison.jpg

Comment: @GiorgioP not really "typical" skin... https://i.stack.imgur.com/GSYCM.jpg

Comment: What IR band are you interested in? At near IR (~0.8 - 1 um) I would expect variation in IR reflectance to correlate pretty well with visible reflectance. At longer wavelengths (10 um and up), IR emissions might make it hard to measure reflectance.

Comment: @ThePhoton In the far IR, skin is quite like a black body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're really asking about near infrared spectroscopy. (NIRS) The main chromophores in tissue are  oxy-hemoglobin, deoxy-hemoglobin, melanin, lipids and scattering. There are a large number of resources on NIRS available online.

[image: The optical properties of a tissue are dependent on the properties of the tissue's constituents (water, oxy-hemoglobin, deoxy-hemgolobin, melanin, fat and scattering).]
https://omlc.org/news/feb15/generic_optics/index.html

https://www.ucl.ac.uk/medical-physics-biomedical-engineering/research/groups-and-centres/biomedical-optics-research-laboratory-borl